# How do I calculate the greatest guarantee period through normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The full question says:

"If the life of a car engine, calculated in miles, is normally distributed, with a mean of 240,000 miles and a standard deviation of 18,500 miles, what is the greatest the guarantee period should be if the company wants less than 2% of the engines to fail while under warranty?"

I've been learning standard distribution for the past couple weeks but have really struggled when I actually get questions. I understand the z score equation to solve it:

[Z score equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTwda.png)

I also know how to use the table but I need to have a better understanding of questions like this. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that engine life is normally distributed (which is questionable in practice), you have $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 240, \sigma =18.5),$ in thousands of miles. You want $k$ such
that $P(X <k) = 0.02.$

**Using software:** In R, where `qnorm` is a normal quantile function (inverse CDF):

```
qnorm(.02, 240, 18.5)
[1] 202.0056
pnorm(202, 240, 18.5)
[1] 0.01998523
pnorm(200, 240, 18.5)
[1] 0.01530284
```

So 202,000 miles is the largest limit. Maybe easier to
say it's a 200,000 mile guarantee.

**Using printed normal tables:** Using standardization and printed normal CDF tables you would have the following.

$$P(X < k) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{k - 240}{18.5}\right) = 0.02.$$

Then from a printed table find the z-score that cuts probability $0.02$ from the lower tail of the standard normal distribution. Look in the *body* of the table to find a value (nearly) equivalent to probability  $0.0200$ (of being smaller), and then read the z-score from the margins.
Maybe $z = -2.05.$ Then solve $\frac{k-240}{18.5} = -2.05$
to get a reasonable approximation of $k.$

[image]

Comment: I'm using a Casio fx-9750GII calculator. Where can I find an equivalent to Inverse CDF?